# Cause for segmentation fault; pointer value lost after function call

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a segmentation fault error after the call to function, 'flightdynamics'. The pointer 'impulsevecnorm' seems to 'loose' it's value (i.e. if I try and access elements it's pointing to, I get a segmentation fault error). If I pass 'impulsevecnorm' to the function, 'flightdynamics', I can print out it's value uptil the return statement but after return, back in main(), it looses it's value. This is odd because in 'flightdynamics' I'm not accessing or changing the value of 'impulsevecnorm' explicitly, so I do not understand why it should 'lose' it's value after. Here's the code:

```
int main()
{

double *currstate, *nextstate;
  double *impulsevecnorm;

 /* Start a few for loops */
              srand(time(NULL));

          currstate = initialize (vx0, vy0);
          impulsevecnorm = impulsecalc (currstate);
          for (i=0; i<NBALLS; i++)
            {
                double terrain[(int) (NSTEPS*2)] = {0};
                double terrainsl[(int) (NSTEPS*2)] = {0};

                  for (j=0; j<NSTEPS; j++)
                  {

                  printf("%f \n",impulsevecnorm[1]); // At this point it prints fine
                  nextstate = flightdynamics (currstate, terrain, terrainsl, bcounter, tcounter);
                  printf("%f \n",impulsevecnorm[1]); // here i get a segmentation fault and the code stops running
                  ..... 
                  /* to end of function (rest doesn't matter as error appears before this)*/
}}}

double * flightdynamics (double *state, double terrain[], double terrainsl[], double counter, int endterr)
{                                                                                      
    double *out = (double *)malloc ( (NSTATE+3)*sizeof(double) );
    double *hit = (double *)malloc ( 3*sizeof(double) );
    double tx[sizet] = {0}, theight[sizet] = {0};

    for (j = 0; j < sizet; j++)
    {
        tx[j] = ((double) endterr/refine + (double) j)*space;
        theight[j] = randomground();
    }

    gsl_interp_accel *acc = gsl_interp_accel_alloc();
    gsl_spline *spline = gsl_spline_alloc(gsl_interp_akima, sizet);
    gsl_spline_init(spline, tx, theight,sizet);

    for (i = (int) endterr; i< (int) endterr + (int) ((sizet-1)*refine/space); i++)
    {
        terrain[i] = gsl_spline_eval(spline,xi,acc);
        terrainsl[i] = gsl_spline_eval_deriv(spline,xi,acc);
        xi = xi+(double) space/refine;
    }

    newendterr = endterr + sizet*refine/space;

     hit = intersect(vylift,vxlift,xlift,ylift,terrain,(int) (xlift*refine/space),newendterr);

    landx = hit[0];
    thland = terrainsl[(int) (landx*(double)refine/space)];
        out[0] = hit[1]; /*xland */
        out[1] = hit[2]; /*yland  */
        tflight = (out[0] - xlift)/vxlift;
        out[3] = vylift - g*tflight; /* vyland */
      out[2] = vxlift; /* vxland */
      out[4] = philift + wlift*tflight; /* philand */
      out[5] = wlift; /* wland */
      out[6] = thland;
      out[7] = landx;
      out[8] = (double) newendterr;

// if I pass impulsevecnorm to this function I can still print out it's value using printf here

 return out;
}

double* intersect (double vy, double vx, double currx, double curry, double terrainy[], int counter, int endterr)
{
    double* out = (double *)malloc ( 3*sizeof(double) );
    out[0]=-1;

for (i = counter+1; i < endterr + (sizet-1)*refine; i++)
{
    xball = (double) i*deltax;

    for(j=start; j<endl; j++)
    {
        xt = (double) j*deltax;
        if (pow(xball-xt,2)+pow((vx*vy*(xball-currx)-g*pow(xball-currx,2)+vx*vx*(curry-terrainy[j]))/(vx*vx),2)<= (double) (rball*rball) && j!=counter)
        {
            out[0] = xt;
            out[1] = xball;
            out[2] = (vx*vy*(xball-currx)-g*pow(xball-currx,2)+vx*vx*curry)/(vx*vx);
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        break;
    }
}
return out;
}

double * impulsecalc (double *state)
{
  double *out1 = (double *)malloc ( ((int)(NSTATE/2)) * sizeof(double) );
    out1[0]= (1 - rt)*state[2] - rball*rt*state[5] +
            rball*(MI*state[5] + m*rball*((-1 + rt)*state[2] + rball*rt*state[5]))/
            (MI + m*rball*rball);
    out1[1]= (1 - rn)*state[3];
    out1[2]= state[5] - (MI*state[5] + m*rball*((-1 + rt)*state[2] + rball*rt*state[5]))/
            (MI + m*rball*rball);
  return out1;
}
```

To make the code shorter I am omitting all variable definitions apart from the pointer definitions. Trust that all other variables have been properly defined. The functions flightdynamics and intersect are long but I didn't want to hide any bit of code for the sake of brevity in case the source of the error was also left out.

I'm an amateur programmer. Started working with C only recently. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IMHO, this is not a `short` code.

Comment: and what's the output of `gdb`?

Comment: and what is `**printf(...`?

Comment: It's not causing your issue, but you are leaking memory (you don't call `free` anywhere). Specifically there are places where you should be `free`ing `hit`, or not `malloc`ing it in the first place.

Comment: valgrind is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. The problem was in the terrain and terrainsl arrays. I initialized them with too little space. Was exceeding array bounds in the for loop in the flightdynamics function.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing to `state[4]` in your method. If `state` has less than 5 elements, you are writing to another memory location, which might be `impulsevecnorm`.

Without any indication what `initialize (vx0, vy0);` might return, I'd guess that it returns less than 5 elements.